# GLPaint rotate brush

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, paint, brush

I am new in OpenGl and right now I am trying to extend provided by Apple GLpaint example and implement brush rotating.
I have found following code, which I have tried to apply a lot of different ways inside renderLineFromPoint:toPoint: method of PaintingView (GLpaint example), where 'angle' is value in grad  (45 for example)

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.5,0.5,0.0);
glRotatef(angle,0.0,0.0,1.0);
glTranslatef(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

but instead of rotating the brush, it has rotated the whole line which this method have to stroke. 
How glRotatef() have to be properly applied in order rotate just the brush?